# Show out of Stock For Configurable Products in magento

Tags: magento

I have attribute set for my configurable products
i want to show out of stock for the L size of product in my select size drop down

[image]
i got a code for this but that is for magento 1.4 and am using magento 1.6

the Code is

in mage/catalog/block/product/view/type/configurable.php, in line ~85 you have something like this :

```
foreach ($this->getAllowAttributes() as $attribute) {
                $productAttribute = $attribute->getProductAttribute();
                $attributeValue = $product->getData($productAttribute->getAttributeCode());

                if (!isset($options[$productAttribute->getId()])) {
                    $options[$productAttribute->getId()] = array();
                }

                if (!isset($options[$productAttribute->getId()][$attributeValue])) {
                    $options[$productAttribute->getId()][$attributeValue] = array();
                }
                $options[$productAttribute->getId()][$attributeValue][] = $productId;



            }
```

so, in that foreach loop , preferably right after the foreach line, insert this code:

```
$options['qty'][$product -> getAttributeText($productAttribute->getName())] = floor($product->getStockItem()->getQty());
```

after, in line ~128 you have something like this:

```
$info['options'][] = array(
                        'id'    => $value['value_index'],
                        'label' =>  $value['label'] ,
                        'price' => $this->_preparePrice($value['pricing_value'], $value['is_percent']),
                        'products'   => isset($options[$attributeId][$value['value_index']]) ? $options[$attributeId][$value['value_index']] : array(),
                    );
replace it with this :

$info['options'][] = array(
                        'id'    => $value['value_index'],
                        'label' => ($options['qty'][$value['label']] <= 0) ? $value['label'] . ' * out of stock' : $value['label'] . " * (".$options['qty'][$value['label']]." in stock)",
                        'price' => $this->_preparePrice($value['pricing_value'], $value['is_percent']),
                        'products'   => isset($options[$attributeId][$value['value_index']]) ? $options[$attributeId][$value['value_index']] : array(),
                    );
```

can anyone please tell me what will be changes according to magento1.6 ?

Comment: This one worked for me: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/25393/P15/#t200373
don't forget to read this as well: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/25393/P15/#t237141

Answer (score -1):

Create your own module, and in the config.xml file add these 2 events inside the  tag:

```
<events>
    <controller_action_layout_render_before_catalog_product_view>
        <observers>
            <namespace_module>
                <class>module/observer</class>
                <method>showOutOfStock</method>
            </namespace_module>
        </observers>
    </controller_action_layout_render_before_catalog_product_view>
    <controller_action_layout_render_before_checkout_cart_configure>
        <observers>
            <namespace_module>
                <class>module/observer</class>
                <method>showOutOfStock</method>
            </namespace_module>
        </observers>
    </controller_action_layout_render_before_checkout_cart_configure>
</events>
```

Now create an observer inside app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Model/Observer.php

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Observer {
    public function showOutOfStock($observer){
        Mage::helper('catalog/product')->setSkipSaleableCheck(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a problem with this solution. See here:http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/48196/78